# Who to call Custom Mixin Function on Built-in-Model Operational Hook in LoopBack?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a Mixin Script in common/mixin/log.js file

```
module.exports = function (Model, options) {
var app = Model.app;

Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
    // Log CREATE/UPDATE operations on every model
    next();
});
};
```

My server/model.config.json file is

```
{
    "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have model common/models/class.js and related json file is common/model/class.json

```
{
    "name": "class",
    ...
    "mixins": {
        "Log": true
    },
    ...
}
```

When I try any CREATED/UPDATE Operations

```
Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next)
```

is working properly, But I also want to call this function on User model (Built in User model) CREATED/UPDATE Operations but it not working although I added the following lines to node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.json

```
"mixins": {
        "Log": true
    }
```

Do any one know where is problem in my implementation??

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of prustration finaly I get the solution on github
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1973#issuecomment-172760264

**SOLUTION**

The built-in models are a bit different in this regard, as they don't fully participate in the loopback-boot loading cycle. Please create a file: server/boot/user.js and try something like:

```
module.exports = function(app) {                                                              
   var User = app.models.User;
   User.mixin('Log');
};
```